# MatTable not getting updated at a fixed interval

Tags: html, angular, timer, datasource, angular-material-table

I am a little new to angular so I am not sure how this would be done. I want to show the duration as a column in Table in form of HH:mm:ss. So the duration column should be updated like a timer each second. But I am not able to do so. And i dont want my whole datasource to be called every second.

```
dataSource: bookingFilteringDatasource;
  subscription: Subscription;
  everyFiveSeconds: Observable<number> = timer(0, 1000);
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource = this.zetChargeService.getbookingFilteringDataSource();
    this.fetch_event_list();
    this.refresh.next();
    const inputChanges = [fromEvent(this.filter.nativeElement, 'keyup')];
    this.subscription = this.everyFiveSeconds.subscribe(() => {
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator
    });

    merge(...inputChanges)
      .pipe(debounceTime(500), distinctUntilChanged())
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.dataSource &&
          this.dataSource.setSearchString(this.filter.nativeElement.value);
        this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
      });

    this.filter.nativeElement.focus();
    this.currentDateTime = new Date();
    this.utcTime();
  }

   convertMillisecondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (startTime, stopTime) {
     console.log("check time")
    let a  =  new Date(startTime)
    let b  = new Date(stopTime)
    let diff = b.getTime() - a.getTime()
    const seconds = Math.floor((diff / 1000) % 60);
    const minutes = Math.floor((diff / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    const hours = Math.floor((diff / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24);
    return `${this.pad(hours, 2)} : ${this.pad(minutes, 2)} : ${this.pad(seconds, 2)}`;
  };
```

This is my ts file. My html file is below

`

```
        <ng-template #pastPresentRow>
          <div
            *ngIf="
              (element.toDate | date : 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss') <
                (currentDateTime | date : 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss');
              then pastRow;
              else presentRow
            ">
            here is ignored
          </div>
          <ng-template #pastRow>
            {{this.convertMillisecondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(element.bookingInfo.startChargingTime, element.bookingInfo.stopChargingTime)}}
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template #presentRow>
            <div
              *ngIf="element.isBookingActive; then ongoingRow; else waitingRow">
              here is ignored
            </div>
            <ng-template #ongoingRow>
               {{this.convertMillisecondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(element.bookingInfo.startChargingTime, currentDateTime) }} 

          </ng-template>
            <ng-template #waitingRow>
             -- : --: -- 
            </ng-template>
          </ng-template>
        </ng-template>
```

If there is any other way please do let me know. Thanks in advance

As mentioned in various other stackoverflow solutions, I tried to use changeDetector. Also tried using paginator to refresh datasrouce, but was not able to use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use ngx-timer, which does live update of time. Here is the link. [ngx-timer](https://npm.io/package/ngx-timer)